# Lie derivative of Riemann tensor along killing vector ( = 0 )

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I'm currently learning the mathematical framework for General Relativity, and I'm trying to prove that the Lie derivative of the Riemann curvature tensor is zero along a killing vector.

With the following notation for covariant differentiation, $A_{a||b} $ (instead of $\nabla_b A_a$ ), I have the following:

$\it\unicode{xA3}_\xi R_{amsq} = R_{amsq||x} \xi ^x + R_{xmsq} \xi^x{}_{||a} + R_{axsq} \xi^x{}_{||m} + R_{amxq} \xi^x{}_{||s} + R_{amsx} \xi^x{}_{||q}$.

I suspect that I need to invoke the second Bianchi identity. However, before I can do this, I need to somehow get this into a different form. There has to be some property of either killing vectors or maybe covariant derivatives that I'm forgetting/failed to learn. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This was done as part of the following answer: (http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88655/)

Comment: Yes it was. However, I had difficulty understanding that answer and would like to understand how to do it _this_ way. That is to say, I'd really like to know what property or identity that I'm missing before I can use use the Bianchi identities to show that it is manifestly zero.

Comment: (LfX)(p) = f(p)(LX)(p) + (df) ^ (iX)(p)``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I had difficulty understanding that answer and would like to understand how to do it *this* way. That is to say, I'd really like to know what property or identity that I'm missing before I can use use the Bianchi identities to show that it is manifestly zero.

The [other proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88677/1353) uses the first Bianchi identity. That's where the starting assumption $R^a{}_{bcd}\xi^d = \xi^a{}_{;bc}$ comes from. If you want to use the second Bianchi identity, it is
$$(\nabla_\xi R)(X,Y) + (\nabla_X R)(Y,\xi) + (\nabla_Y R)(\xi,X) = 0\text{,}$$
and therefore applying it and the Leibniz rule produces:
$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{\nabla_\xi[R(X,Y)]+\nabla_X[R(Y,\xi)]+\nabla_Y[R(\xi,X)]}_\mathrm{foo} = \underbrace{R(\mathcal{L}_\xi X,Y) + R(\mathcal{L}_XY,\xi) + R(\mathcal{L}_Y\xi,X)}_\mathrm{bar}\text{,}
\end{align}$$
where it was assumed that the torsion vanishes, so that $\mathcal{L}_AB = \nabla_AB-\nabla_BA$. Additionally,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(\mathcal{L}_\xi R)(X,Y) &=& \mathcal{L}_\xi[R(X,Y)] - R(\mathcal{L}_\xi X,Y) - R(X,\mathcal{L}_\xi Y)\\
&=&\mathcal{L}_\xi[R(X,Y)] - R(\mathcal{L}_\xi X,Y) - R(\mathcal{L}_Y\xi,X)\\
&=&\underbrace{\mathcal{L}_\xi[R(X,Y)] - [\mathrm{foo}] + R(\mathcal{L}_XY,\xi)}_\mathrm{qux}\text{.}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
So the objective is to show that the right-hand side, $\mathrm{qux}$, is identically zero whenever $\xi$ is a Killing vector field.

Let's write $S^a{}_b = [R(X,Y)]^a{}_b = R^a{}_{bcd}X^cY^d$, and just crank it out:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L}_\xi S^a{}_b &=& \nabla_\xi S^a{}_b - S^e{}_b\xi^a{}_{;e} + S^a{}_e\xi^e{}_{;b}\\
&=& \nabla_\xi S^a{}_b + X^cY^d(R^a{}_{ecd}\xi^e{}_{;b} - R^e{}_{bcd}\xi^a{}_{;e})\\
&=& \nabla_\xi S^a{}_b + X^cY^d(\nabla_c\nabla_d-\nabla_d\nabla_c)\xi^a{}_{;b}\text{,}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the last step is actually valid for arbitrary $Z^a{}_b$, not just $\xi^a{}_{;b}$. The first term of this cancels with the first term of $\mathrm{foo}$. So far we have not used the fact that $\xi$ is a Killing vector field. Let's do so now by considering the other two terms of $\mathrm{foo}$:
$$\nabla_X[R(Y,\xi)]^a{}_b - \nabla_Y[R(X,\xi)]^a{}_b = \nabla_X\nabla_Y\xi^a{}_{;b} - \nabla_Y\nabla_X\xi^a{}_{;b}\text{,}$$
where the starting identity $R^a{}_{bcd}\xi^d = \xi^a{}_{;bc}$ was used. The same identity also gives:
$$R(\mathcal{L}_XY,\xi)^a{}_{b} = \nabla_{[X,Y]}\xi^a{}_{;b}\text{.}$$
Therefore, we have shown that for any vector fields $X,Y$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
X^cY^d(\mathcal{L}_\xi R^a{}_{bcd}) &=& \left[X^cY^d(\nabla_c\nabla_d-\nabla_d\nabla_c)-(\nabla_X\nabla_Y-\nabla_Y\nabla_X) + \nabla_{[X,Y]}\right]\xi^a{}_{;b}\\
&=& 0\text{.}\end{eqnarray*}$$
(If you have trouble with the last step, check [Christoph's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88705/1353) to the other question and modify appropriately.) Thus $\mathcal{L}_\xi R^a{}_{bcd} = 0$, QED.

Comment: Ah, now I see! The first line you posted has exactly what I needed, that is, $R^a{}_{bcd} \xi^d = \xi^a{}_{;bc}$. I've got the rest under control. Thanks.